# Method and Loop to check substring of Array List doesn't seem to be returning correct value in Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

working on a few different methods to check that a code entered meets the criteria of 3 Characters and 3 Intergers i.e. ABC123 or JJJ111 etc I then also need to check if this code is used in an array list of objects that include a name and code i.e. Programming in Java, ITC206.

I have written two methods in a subject class to check the rerquirements are met, that the code doesnt already exist, but I am having a couple of issues. the first one isValidCode, seems to run through the loop but only returns false is there are not 6 characters, the .isAlphabetic and .isDigit methods don't seem to be affecting the outcome.

The second method, being codeExists just returns false all the time, even if the code is a new one and not being used.

I have tried changing a couple of things around and can't seem to figure out what is wrong with either..

Below are the methods and the main class I am using to check.

```
public boolean isValidCode (String subjectCode){
    boolean validCode = true;
    if (subjectCode.length() !=6){
            validCode = false;               
            String codeLetters = subjectCode.substring(0, 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < codeLetters.length(); i++){
                Character letters = subjectCode.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isAlphabetic(letters)) 
                    validCode = false; break;
            }
            String codeDigits = subjectCode.substring(3, subjectCode.length());
            for (int j = 3; j < codeDigits.length(); j++){
                Character digits = subjectCode.charAt(j);
                if (!Character.isDigit(digits)) 
                    validCode = false; break;
            } 
        }                 
    return validCode;
}

public boolean codeExist (String code, List<Subject> subjectList){
    
    boolean exists = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < subjectList.size(); i++){
        Subject newSubject = subjectList.get(i);
        String subject = newSubject.getSubjectCode();
        if (subject.equals(code)){  
        }
    }   
    return exists;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create array list        
    List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // inport scanner
    //add a new object ot the array list
    subjectList.add(new Subject("Programming in Java", "ITC206"));
    subjectList.add(new Subject("Cyber Ethics", "ITC311"));
    subjectList.add(new Subject("IT Helpdesk", "ITC232"));
    showSubjectList(subjectList);
    
    //user to add name and codes to list
    String newName = "Test";
    String newCode = "AAA123";
    Subject newSubject = new Subject(newName, newCode);
    
    boolean valid = newSubject.isValidCode(newCode);
    System.out.println(valid);
    
    
    boolean exists = newSubject.codeExist(newCode, subjectList);
    System.out.println(exists);
    
    showSubjectList(subjectList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex in your `isValidCode` method to check if your code follows a certain pattern:

in your case `"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}"` 3 capital letters followed by 3 digits:

```
public boolean isValidCode (String subjectCode){
    String regex = "[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}";
    return subjectCode.matches(regex);
}
```

Your `codeExist` method, provided you use java 8 or higher, can be rewritten as follows:

```
public boolean codeExist (String code, List<Subject> subjectList){
    return subjectList.stream()
                      .map(Subject::getSubjectCode)
                      .anyMatch(code::equals);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with regex classes yet but this worked a treat and is much easier to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

`codeExist()` does return the variable `exists` which is always false. You should just return `true` if your check matches.

```
public boolean codeExist (String code, List<Subject> subjectList){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < subjectList.size(); i++){
        Subject newSubject = subjectList.get(i);
        String subject = newSubject.getSubjectCode();
        if (subject.equals(code)){  
            return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! something so simple was missing. that does solve the second method constantly returning false. Any suggestion on the isCodeValid method?